# Saving files and images in a folder in the project using relative path

Tags: c#, path, directory

In my project I will eventually have to save images created or took on the net and save other created files, which I know how to do. The problem is that when I happen to save my images, I work like this:

```
using (var imgClient = new WebClient())
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(imagesDirectory);
    imgClient.DownloadFile(imgUrl, imagesDirectory + m_ObjNameToUse + "(" + abv+ ")" + objNumber + ".jpeg");
}
```

I call the `Directory.CreateDirectory` method at this moment to make sure that the directory is always created before creating the image, preventing a crash.

Now my problem is that it uses the string imagesDirectory, which is a hard coded string looking like this:

```
string imagesDirectory = "C:\\Creation_Folder\\Object_Sets\\Images\\" + _objSetName+ "\\";
```

That works, as of right now. But I'm under development and the project will eventually be released. I would like to save the images under the "Images" folder in the project, adding the _objSetName as a new folder to distinguish each images created to avoid having too many images in the same file.

So my question is how can I tell my app to locate the `Images` folder included in the project, and then create a folder under `_objSetName`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using your application base folder `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseFolder`. This is the folder where your application is located. From there it is easy:

```
 string imagesDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseFolder + "Object Sets\\Images\\" + _objSetName+ "\\";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string imagesDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Images", _objSetName);
```

Side note, you will probably want to store images in a folder like `AppData` where your user is guaranteed to have write access.  Subdirectories of your application will likely only be accessible by machine administrators.

Comment: Well, in a way, I would like those images to be protected, so not allowing write access is maybe a good idea. Anyway, I'm going to try what you just suggested and get you back soon.

Comment: Environment.CurrentDirectory is allowed to be changed during the course of the life time of the application. This whay the application could loose track of its images.

Comment: This provoked an error, because it references me to the IIS file of my computer, not the current folder where the application is deployed.

Comment: @HerveS - The current directory is IIS because thats where the application is being ran from.  This code is actually correct.